# su behaves differently on adb and on program

Tags: android, root, superuser

I have a custom device android 4.3. Problem occurs with some commands, one of an example:

```
su -c 'pm enable com.android.systemui'
```

When I run this command over adb it works. However when I run the code programatically using [this](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser) library it just does not work, no error is shown as well.

Interesting observations:

```
Shell.SU.available() : false
Shell.SU.isSELinuxEnforcing() : false
```

Comment: via `adb`, you are allowed to do that command even if your device is not rooted however that commend will fail if device is not rooted regardless of what library you use. So if the physical device actually rooted?

Comment: @th3pat3l , device is rooted by default. So, I can run most of the root commands. for example when I execute "reboot" command alone, it will not work. However if I execute it as root device reboots.

Comment: I posted an answer. See if that helps you out

Answer (score 0):

Ok so device is rooted.  Any reason why you are trying to do that command using that library?

What I am trying to say is why can't you just run the shell command yourself?

`runRootCommand` method:

```
static boolean runRootCommand(String command) {
    boolean status = true;
    DataOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        status = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (os != null)
                os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            status = false;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

And then call that method like this:

```
boolean success = runRootCommand("pm enable com.android.systemui");

if(success) {
    // command was successful
} else {
    // command was NOT successful
}
```

This will run the command as "su" (superuser).
Hope this helps.

Comment: problem is not how can I execute commands as su. The problem is su itself.  Question is how can I achieve level of access just as adb root.

Comment: If your device is rooted, you already have "level of access" you are looking for. It's just a matter of doing it the right way. If you want to test it out, download the terminal app from play store and execute the command. it will work.